# apt packages - static vs dynamic libraries

Tags: apt, shared-library, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I install libraries using apt, for example:

```
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev
```

Does apt always install dynamic libraries or I can determine if a package contains static or dynamic library ?

Comment: `apt` will install whatever the package maintainers decided to include. This will typically be dynamic libraries, but there can be a reason to include the static libraries for developers who want to do static builds.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the type of library using some apt command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[By convention](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#static-libraries): `libfoo1` will contain a dynamic library, while `libfoo-dev` will create the headers and static library.

`libfoo1` is only runtime dependencies, and dynamic libraries are runtime dependencies.

`libfoo-dev` is a build-dependency, and static libraries are only used during building/linking.

If you want to know what's in a library, you can use `dpkg` to look at what's in an installed package:

```
$ dpkg -L libfoo1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.1.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libfoo1/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfoo1/copywrite
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.1
```

If the package is not installed, you can use the `apt-file` command, but you need to have recently used `apt update` to get the file list.

```
$ apt-file list libfoo-dev
libfoo-dev: /usr/include/foo.h
libfoo-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.a
libfoo-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so
```

`libfoo.so` (in `libfoo-dev`) is actually just a symbolic link to `libfoo.so.1` (in `libfoo1`) which itself is a symbolic link to `libfoo.so.1.0.0` (also in `libfoo1`).